# Sending Email to @facebook

Tags: php, facebook, email

```
<?php
$to = "adi.mathur2@facebook.com, ";
$subject = " Hi ";
$message = "  this time..  ";
$from = "aditya169@facebook.com";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: aditya169@facebook.com\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f$from");
echo " successful!!";
?>
```

I am trying to send this email but it doesn't send to the Facebook Email. When I change the to field to my Gmail ID then I can receive the Email.

Is it that the email is marked as Spam? or something? I cant even see the email in the Other folder on Facebook.

Comment: It might be a protective thing for facebook not to accept emails from its own domain unless its sent from its own servers. When using the mail function, you're using your servers own mail server to send the email. Try a different from address and see whether or not that works.

Comment: @h2ooooooo _ I tried both my Email ID's too , Still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Messages send to *{user}@facebook.com* that are not coming from friends are put into the `Messages/Other` subfolder, and I think they don’t even generate a notification in the Facebook top bar – so the user will most likely only recognize them “by accident”.

Also, somewhere in the docs Facebook say these email addresses are intended solely for user-to-user communication, and that apps **should not** use this as a way to communicate with their users. App requests are the designated way to do the latter.

Comment: @Cbone - I am not getting the Email even in Others Folder .

Comment: As h2ooooooo already said, that might be some kind of spam protection/filtering applied by Facebook. I only know I tested this once with my @gmail.com address, under which my Facebook account is registered – and that message showed up in my friend’s messages (as if it was coming directly from my FB account).